# Correct way to show a row with incomplete content, using Apple's human interface guidelines?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, human-computer-interface

I'm trying to display a tableview row with content that shows a warning that the content is incomplete and needs to be edited further before the content can be used.

One method I've come upon is where the user would tap on a disclosure button, and this would then reveal that the content isn't complete.  When the user taps the disclosure button, and alert is presented.

[image]

Another method I've wondered about would be using some kind of warning or alert button the user taps, which then presents the alert as follows:

[image]

I'm concerned that this approach might be contrary to Apple's human interface guidelines.  I'm curious to know the recommended method of helping the user to recognize when a row contains content that needs further revision before it is valid.

Thanks

Comment: I doubt there is specific Apple guidance for your specific use case but I would suggest careful consideration for whatever icon/image you choose to use. The info button doesn't imply 'unfinished' and the red ! in a triangle is usually reserved for DANGER! so probably isn't what you want to use either.

Comment: Why don’t you simply display an “incomplete“ tag with a not-so-dangerous background color (orange, for example) and allow the user to supply the missing info by tapping the row which would advance to the edit view controller? Also, you might want to refrain from over-using alert views as they force the user to confirm each time they show up.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question for Apple support/guidelines, not Stack Overflow.